# Laravel 4 - model method not found

Tags: methods, laravel, model

I have added the `profiles` method to the `User` model like so:

```
<?php

class User extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function profiles()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('Profile');
        }

}
```

However, when I try to use this relation:

`$profile = $user->profiles()->save($profile);`

I get the following error:

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::profiles()`

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

It should be something like this:

```
$profile = $user->profiles->first()->save($profile);
```

It's because, `$user->profiles()` returns a collection of `Profile` models because the relations is `hasMany` and on a collection (without selecting any `profile` model) you can't call `save()` method.

But the error is not for that, instead it's rising because you have used `profiles()`, it should be `profiles`.

Btw, I think you should declare a relation between `User` and `Profile` model using `hasOne`, because one `User` can has only one `Profile` so it could be declared like this in your `User` model:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Profile');
}
```

So, you will be able to call the `save()` method like this:

```
$profile = $user->profile->save($profile);
```

Also you should implement two interfaces when creating the `User` model, like this:

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    // Code ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your model class

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
   use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent  implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{
     protected $table = 'users';

```
     protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

     public function profiles()
          {
        return $this->hasMany('Profile');
         }
```

}